# BeEf Famework Kali-2 configuration

Tags: security, kali-linux, vmware, port-forwarding

I am running Kali-2(rolling 1 latest) in Vmware workstation 12. I have forwarded my ports and am using NAT. The beef framework links only seem to work within the local network. Any specific reason? Must I host a server? If yes - then please do direct me. 
Thank you.